# Use a different connection in a static function of Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

In Laravel 5.8 I try to set a different connection for a model.

I have setup 2 database connections in `config/database.php`  (`mysql1` and `mysql2`)

First I made a `MyModel` class:

```
  namespace App\Models;

  class MyModel
  extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public static function sqlselect($sql) {
      $result = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
      return $result;
    }
  }
```

Then I made a new model that is derived from this class and set the connection that it should use:

```
namespace App\Models;

class FooModel extends \App\Models\MyModel {
  protected $connection = 'mysql2';

}
```

When I try to use this `FooModel`, I expect it to use the `mysql2` connection, but it doesn't.

```
use App\Models\FooModel;
$sqlresult = FooModel::sqlselect('SELECT * FROM foo');
```

gives an error that the `foo` table is not in the database, because it still tries to use the default `mysql1` connection.

Any way to do this, while still keeping everything static ?

Comment: DB won't use connection in Model automatically, if you want, just use Model to perform queries

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple connections with laravel:

**Query Builder**

```php
$queryResult = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

**With eloquent:**

```php
class MyModel extends Model {
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
}
```

You can also define the `connection` to be used at runtime:

```php
class MyController extends Controller {

    public function myMethod()
    {
        $myModel = new MyModel;

        $myModel->setConnection('mysql2'); // non-static method

        $queryResult = $myModel->find(1);

        $queryResult = MyModel::on('mysql2')->find(1); // static method

        return $queryResult;
    }
}
```

Laravel docs about [multiple database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#using-multiple-database-connections).

Comment: Thanks. I've read all that, but since MyModel is an abstract class that should have no set connection, this is not the right way. And setting it in the controller is also not an option, since I want to use the model outside of routes too. static::$connection is also not available in MyModel somehow, so I cannot use that either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing what you are doing, nor why you are using `DB` instead of `Eloquent`, but:

```php
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public static function sqlselect($sql) {
        return DB::connection(static::$conn)->select(DB::raw($sql));
    }
}
```

```php
class FooModel extends MyModel
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected static $conn = 'mysql2';
}
```

Define a `static` property inside `FooModel` and reference that in `MyModel`.

Comment: I already came up with the same solution, but I think it's quite ugly to have to define the connection twice. I'm using DB since Eloquent can't do complete raw queries (or could it?)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question but am using Laravel version 9.
Here is the easy way to switch connections (in version 9 at least):

```
public static function employJoe()
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
    $bindings = ['username' => 'Joe', 'password' => 'secret'];
    // uses default connection
    DB::insert($sql, $bindings);
    // uses specific connection
    DB::connection('conn2')->insert($sql, $bindings);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections